# Send EMAIL via PL/SQL script

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

I have the following procedure which I received from Internet

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_email (
p_sender IN VARCHAR2,
p_recipient IN VARCHAR2,
p_message IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
mailcon UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
mailcon := UTL_SMTP.open_connection ('localhost');
UTL_SMTP.helo (mailcon, 'localhost');
UTL_SMTP.mail (mailcon, p_sender);
UTL_SMTP.rcpt (mailcon, p_recipient);
UTL_SMTP.DATA (mailcon,
'From: '
|| p_sender
|| UTL_TCP.crlf
|| 'To: '
|| p_recipient
|| UTL_TCP.crlf
|| 'Subject: SMS From Database'
|| UTL_TCP.crlf
|| p_message
);
UTL_SMTP.quit (mailcon);
END;
```

This procedure is being successfully compiled.
While executing the procedure

```
exec SEND_email('abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com','My first EMAIL');
```

I receive the following error message

ERROR at line 1:

```
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 554 Can not connect to e-mail server. Error:100502
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 17
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 98
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 138
ORA-06512: at "PERFECT.SEND_SMS", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Please help

Comment: Are you sure you have a mail server running locally (i.e. `localhost`)? Do you manage to send simple email?

Comment: @J.Chomel yes its in Local server

Comment: Do you mix "SMS" with "E-Mail"?

Comment: Did you check [ducumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS71460): *The invoking user must have the connect privilege granted in the access control list assigned to the remote network host to which the user must connect.* See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/fine_grained_access.htm#DBSEG99981

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I wanted to but Now I need only to send SMS... So removing that email id will help?? But sender would be from a registered email id and receiver id would be number@<whatever domain that number falls>

Comment: `SMS` = `Short eMail Service` ? Also clearly you are using `Oracle`. Please remove the `SQL Server` tag

Comment: No, "SMS" means `Short Message Service`, completely different to "SMTP" `Simple Mail Transfer Protocal`

Comment: @Squirrel No SMS is short messaging service. Yes iam using oracle

Comment: Have you tried using UTL_MAIL instead?  It's usually much simpler.

Comment: The error indicates that your localhost mail server is accepting the connection, but it's getting SMTP error 554 which is fairly vague one that probably means it's not allowed to connect to the recipient mail server.

Answer (score 0):

## Test it first

Test first if your SMTP server works. You need `telnet` utility (or similar, `nc` netcat may work too) for it.

```
ip-172-31-3-158:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ip-172-31-3-158.eu-west-1.compute.internal ESMTP Exim 4.86_2 Ubuntu Thu, 09 Nov 2017 10:55:59 +0000
MAIL FROM: abc@gmail.com
250 OK
RCPT TO: xyz@gmail.com
250 Accepted
DATA
354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
From: abc@gmail.com
To: xyz@gmail.com
Subject: SMS From Database

message body
.
250 OK id=1eCkVW-00018X-Ak
QUIT
221 ip-172-31-3-158.eu-west-1.compute.internal closing connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
ip-172-31-3-158:~$
```

Then check if you receive `250 OK` and finally if your message arrives to destination email.

## Why it fails

Please note you are sending through `localhost` an email advertising himself as originating from `gmail.com` account. The most probably it will be a problem because your `localhost` SMTP server is not authorized to send emails as `gmail.com`. The email might be instantly rejected or queued and finally dropped.

So it means, the pair: SMTP server and mail domain, are important. Use `smtp.gmail.com` to send as `xx@gmail.com` and use `smtp.acme.org` to send as `yyy@acme.org`. This mechanism is to avoid faking email addresses. This statement is kind of simplification but you get the idea.

## Send as Google

What do you need to do to send as Google user? Connect to Google SMTP server itself  (port 25 will not work, SSL connection is required to `smtp.gmail.com:465`), authenticating yourself and then send an email. Test it with raw SMTP protocol first. It is more complicated than it looks at the first sight - extra db setup is required to reach external SMTP (not localhost one) and SSL might be an issue for Oracle. Look for more practical solution below.

## Practical Solution

Another, better option is to send the email from your organization's SMTP server (or indeed your `localhost`) with your SMTP domain in the email address. Usually organization allow to send email without an authentication, from clients within the organization's IP address range.

So assumming you want to stay with the `localhost`, just **provide the real email address** (assuming you're acme.org and the database runs from `oracle` user, use `from: oracle@acme.org`). "Test it first" - if it works with telnet and the email is delivered, focus on PLSQL part then.